# twitter oauth :geting undefined index: oauth_token_secret in

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi am trying to post tweets using oauth (PHP)

i created the application in my twitter account ,

i executed some open source script but that produce the below error,

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in
```

How to fix this issue

my snippet

```
require_once('twitterOAuth/twitterOAuth.php');
require_once('twitterOAuth/OAuth.php');


$consumer_key='q3fsdfsdfsdw';
$consumer_secret='rfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdL';
$request_token='http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
$request_token_secret='5454545';
$oauth = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret,
$request_token, $request_token_secret);

// Ask Twitter for an access token (and an access token secret)
$request = $oauth->getAccessToken();

$access_token = $request['amp;oauth_token'];
$access_token_secret = $request['oauth_token_secret'];=======> HERE AM GETTING TROUBLE

function getAccessToken($token = NULL, $pin = NULL)
{
    if ($pin)
        $r = $this->oAuthRequest($this->accessTokenURL(),
            array("oauth_verifier" => $pin));
    else
        $r = $this->oAuthRequest($this->accessTokenURL());

    $token = $this->oAuthParseResponse($r);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'],
        $token['oauth_token_secret']);

    return $token;
}
```

My complete Error Here

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in E:\wamp\www\source\oauth\twitterOAuth\twitteroauth.php on line 118

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in E:\wamp\www\source\oauth\bharani.php on line 18
```

Comment: You don't need the `require_once('twitterOAuth/OAuth.php');` as it in required by twitteroauth.php already. Is http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token your actual value for $request_token?

Comment: i just commented the <code>require_once('twitterOAuth/OAuth.php');</code> line , still am getting same error , what should i do next

Comment: Request tokens/secrets are one use tokens so they should not be hard coded into your code.

Answer (score 3):

In your twitter application setting "Callback URL", add any callback url, for ex:
https://dev.twitter.com/

Otherwise twitter will consider your application as desktop application and you will get error:

```
Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'
```

and your php script will give errors like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in twitteroauth.php on line 80
```

But by setting a callback url from php script it will overwrite the default placeholder of callback url and consider your application as a web based application.

Comment: Thanks, this just saved me lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error:

> Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in /web/htdocs/www.xxx.com/home/private/libraries> /twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php on line 118
>
> Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in /web/htdocs/www.xxx.com/home/private/libraries/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php on line 118

Debugging on line what the error specified:

```
function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier = FALSE) {
     // .... code .... //

     $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
     $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
     exit(print_r($token));

     // ... code ....//
}
```

I found this:

> Array ( [ "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> Required oauth_verifier parameter not provided /oauth/access_token .......

After i read some issue on the web and find the solution. In my code i must pass a oauth_verifier:

```
 $request = $oauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
```

Hope i help someone, the problem was that For OAuth 1.0a compliance 'oauth_verifier' is required!

Resource: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443#comment-36618

Apologize for bad English.

Comment: Now twitter switch to new version of API v.1.1 Overview: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview , FAQ: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#rest-api-v11

Answer (score 1):

Please check php companents:

- Curl SSL
- Open SSL
- hash_hmac

Answer (score 1):

@Bharanikumar
AFAIK first you should call the function

```
$request_token = $oauth->getRequestToken();
```

then u will get

```
$request_token['oauth_token']; and $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

then  do below

```
 $URL = $oauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);

 $oauth = new TwitterOAuth('YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY', 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',  $request_token['oauth_token'],$request_token['oauth_token_secret']);  

 $access = $oauth->getAccessToken(NULL, $_GET['pin']);
 $accessToken = $access ['oauth_token'];
 $accessTokenSecret = $access ['oauth_token_secret'];
```

& then apply your code

```
if ($pin)
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is an error in the request so you don't get oauth_token_secret in the respond from Twitter. Check out a simple but elaborate solution here..
http://errorbank.blogspot.com/2012/07/php-twitter-undefined-index.html

Comment: let me know if you want further clarif

Comment: Which is it: simple? or elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved for me by setting a Callback URL in my twitter application settings. http://dev.twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm same this bug.
Because I didn't config OAUTH_CALLBACK.
Hope helpful for you.

Answer (score -2):

It just a Notice.

You didn't defined that array index or something. Paste your full error and the lines around where php writes this notice.

Another way: You can disable with this code:

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I think you don't get oauth_token_secret in the respond from Twitter. Check out john misoskian suggestions, maybe some extensions isn't installed in your php or maybe twitter give back some error info for your request, which you can get from your twitter class.

Comment: Try to print_r($oauth); after this call: $oauth->getAccessToken(); Maybe you will see some errors in the twitter respond.

Comment: You can also try var_dump($oauth->http_code); to see which response code twitter is returning. http://dev.twitter.com/pages/responses_errors